# Mysql fetch last log entry from every month

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a09f7

```
| transid |  artid | number | balance |                       date |
|---------|--------|--------|---------|----------------------------|
|       1 |  GJ220 |     10 |      10 | February, 27 2015 08:51:57 |
|       2 | PJ25x8 |      9 |       9 | February, 27 2015 06:51:57 |
|       3 |  GJ220 |     10 |      20 | February, 27 2015 09:51:57 |
|       4 | PJ25x8 |     -4 |       5 | February, 27 2015 10:51:57 |
|       5 |  GJ220 |    -10 |      10 | February, 27 2015 07:51:57 |
```

My goal is to find the last transaction done for every article in every month and get the balance. If there's no transaction done that month it should report back the value from an earlier month.

Also in the future it should be able to limit the query to a specific year

Comment: All right. Where's your problem? And please post the query you tried.

Comment: I've got no query as I don't know where to start

Comment: If you have no clue about sql, a good start would be a tutorial...or a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is query that will give the output as you desire:

```
select * from log 
   where transid IN 
      (select max(transid) from log 
          group by artid,`date` 
          order by transid desc);
```

Comment: That does it by day of moth, so i replaced date with 'DATE_FORMAT(date, "%M-%y")'

Comment: Is it best to manipulate the months (with data from earlier months) without a change in balance in sql or in my application?

Comment: Yes, it is good. this is sql side change and will make application fast.

Comment: ok, how do I achieve that? If I make a loop it will be very infective if there hasn't been a transaction for years

Comment: I've added this to as my year selector `and date_format(date, '%Y') = 2015`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *from `log` 
   where DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%m-%Y") = "02-2015" 
    group by `artid` 
    order by `date` desc;
```

This is basic idea for you. Hope you find your records.
You need to select the month and get the records of particular month.

You can also calculate sum of your balances like:

```
select `transid`,`artid`,`number`, sum(`balance`) as `balance`,`date` from `log` 
   where DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%m-%Y") = "02-2015"
   group by `artid` 
   order by `date` desc;
```

Comment: No that reports back the first transaction in the month, I've updated my sample table